# Payflow link randomly throwing field missing error in sandbox for Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, paypal-sandbox, payflowlink

I am trying to integrate the *Payflow link with my classic ASP website*. Right now i am using the test account for testing the transactions.

This is the flow, 
- I will have one page on my website which will display the address, name, mail, zip and other required fields for Payflow transaction. The same data will be added in hidden fields also, like

```
    <form method="post" action="https://payflowlink.paypal.com">  
 <input type="hidden" name="INVOICE"   value="<%=request.querystring("idOrder")%>">
 <input type="hidden" name="LOGIN"   value="<%=pVeriSignLogin%>">
 <input type="hidden" name="PARTNER"   value="PayPal">
 <input type="hidden" name="TYPE"   value="S">
 <input type="hidden" name="AMOUNT"   value="<%
     response.write money(request.querystring("ordertotal"))
  %>">

 <input type="hidden" name="DESCRIPTION"value="<%=request.querystring("orderDetails")%>">
 <input type="hidden" name="FIRSTNAME"  value="<%=request.querystring("name")%>">
 <input type="hidden" name="LASTNAME"  value="<%=request.querystring("lastName")%>">
 <input type="hidden" name="ADDRESS"  value="<%=request.querystring("address")%>">
 <input type="hidden" name="CITY"  value="<%=request.querystring("city")%>">
 <input type="hidden" name="STATE"  value="<%=request.querystring("state")&request.querystring("stateCode")%>">
 <input type="hidden" name="ZIP"  value="<%=request.querystring("zip")%>">
 <input type="hidden" name="COUNTRY"  value="<%=request.querystring("country")&request.querystring("countryCode")%>">
 <input type="hidden" name="PHONE"  value="<%=request.querystring("phone")%>">
 <input type="hidden" name="EMAIL"  value="<%=request.querystring("email")%>">            

 <input type="hidden" name="NAMETOSHIP"  value="<%=request.querystring("shippingName")%>">
 <input type="hidden" name="LASTNAMETOSHIP"  value="<%=request.querystring("shippingLastName")%>">
 <input type="hidden" name="ADDRESSTOSHIP"  value="<%=request.querystring("ShippingAddress")%>">
 <input type="hidden" name="CITYTOSHIP"  value="<%=request.querystring("ShippingCity")%>">
 <input type="hidden" name="STATETOSHIP"  value="<%=request.querystring("ShippingState")&request.querystring("ShippingStateCode")%>">
 <input type="hidden" name="ZIPTOSHIP"  value="<%=request.querystring("ShippingZip")%>">
<input type="hidden" name="COUNTRYTOSHIP"  value="<%=request.querystring("country")&request.querystring("ShippingCountryCode")%>">
 <input type="hidden" name="PHONETOSHIP"  value="<%=request.querystring("shippingPhone")%>">
 <input type="hidden" name="EMAILTOSHIP"  value="<%=request.querystring("shippingEmail")%>">
```

- On action of previous form data will be transferred to, "https://payflowlink.paypal.com". Here the fields will be auto filled as we had passed data from previous page. User will now add its, Credit Card num and expiry date.

Till here everything works fine as per expectations. Now if i click on "Pay Now" button, i am getting the message,

> Some required information is missing or incorrect. Please correct the fields below and try again.

```
  Error: Address is a required field.
  Error: State is a required field.
  Error: Zip Code is a required field.
  Error: Ship To Address is a required field.
  Error: Ship To State is a required field.
  Error: Ship To Zip Code is a required field.
```

Strange thing is that i already passed this data and payflow link form had already **rendered them in fields**. This issue occurs on random bases. Sometimes when i click on **"Pay Now" option it completes transaction successfully**, and send to success page also.

Is any one had ever faced same issue? I dont know how to solve it. Dont know if it is payflow link sandbox issue or any issue with my way.

Comment: Are you sure the request to this page is carrying all that data on the _querystring_?  Seems strange to me I would expect that level of data to come from a form using a POST method and therefore you would is `Request.Form` not `QueryString`.

Comment: That is not an issue as the payflow form already capture the data passed by me as POST and render them to fields. So Request.Form or Querystring is not a concern here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using the below link,

https://www.x.com/node/2749